# FIDO2 Keys / Windows Hello - Disable password signin

Tags: security, windows-authentication, two-factor-authentication

Is it possible to force a user to use a FIDO2 key to sign in with Windows 10?

Currently, it appears to be a secondary option (along side the standard password option).

Comment: It currently isn’t possible to require the use of Windows Hello and disable password authentication entirely

Comment: I was hoping it would help stop members of my company being tricked by phishing attacks. But it really won't without the ability to disable other authentication methods, right?

Comment: Because it's not possible to prevent a user changing their password in office 365/azure ad

Comment: You can certainly configure how often the password can be chnaged

Comment: So I can prevent it being changed all together? Azure AD / Office 365 and on machines? I didn't think I could?